# Issue with robot_pose_ekf

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

Currently I am trying to use robot_pose_ekf package to get odometry data fused with yaw. But while launching the file i am getting the below error

robot_pose_ekf: /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-bfl-0.7.0-3precise-20140617-0122/src/wrappers/matrix/matrix_BOOST.cpp:283: virtual MatrixWrapper::Matrix MatrixWrapper::Matrix::inverse() const: Assertion `res == 0' failed.

I have enabled the debug for robot_pose_ekf and i can see data for both odo and yaw in the respective temporary files /tmp/odom and /tmp/imu_data which prompts me to assume the data is getting published correctly.

If i disable the odo_used parameter in the launch file for robot_pose_ekf , the package doesnt hang.

Attahing the launch files for robot_pose_ekf and the corresponding publiher file
Launch File:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
            <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
            <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
            <param name="sensor_timeout" value="4.0"/>
            <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
            <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
            <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
            <param name="debug" value="true"/>
            <param name="self_diagnose" value="false"/>
    </node>

    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_footprint yaw 100"/>
```

Publisher Code:
`int main(int argc, char** argv){

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "security_robot_publisher");
ros::NodeHandle security_robot_publisher_Node;
    //Subscribe to ODO data
    ucRespMsg= security_robot_publisher_Node.subscribe("uc0Response", 100, ucCommandCallback);

//Publisher for odo data
ros::Publisher odom_pub = security_robot_publisher_Node.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 50);  
//Publisher for calibrated yaw
ros::Publisher yaw_pub = security_robot_publisher_Node.advertise<sensor_msgs::Imu>("imu_data",50);  

current_time = ros::Time::now();
last_time = ros::Time::now();

ros::Rate r(100.0);

while(security_robot_publisher_Node.ok()){

        ros::spinOnce();     
    current_time = ros::Time::now();          
    //Publish Odometry data into odo topic
    security_robot_odo_publisher(&odom_pub);

    //Publish calibrated Yaw data into yaw topic
    security_robot_yaw_publisher(&yaw_pub);
        r.sleep();
    last_time = current_time;
}
```

}

void security_robot_odo_publisher(ros::Publisher *odom_pub)
{
tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;

```
double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;
double th = 0.0;

double vx = 0.3;//0.1;
double vy = -0.1;
double vth = 0.3;//0.1;

double delta_x = 0;
double delta_y = 0;
double delta_th = 0;
double dt = (current_time -last_time).toSec();  


rwheel_abs_ticks_pres = rwheel_abs_ticks;
lwheel_abs_ticks_pres = lwheel_abs_ticks;

Dleft = (2*(pi)*(radius)*(lwheel_abs_ticks_pres - lwheel_abs_ticks_prev))/N;
Dright = (2*(pi)*(radius)*(rwheel_abs_ticks_pres - rwheel_abs_ticks_prev))/N;

Dcentre = (Dleft +Dright)/2;

ROS_INFO("DL:%lf, DR:%lf, DC:%lf",Dleft,Dright,Dcentre);
ROS_INFO("x:%lf, y:%lf, th:%lf",x,y,th);

delta_x = Dcentre*cos(th);
delta_y = Dcentre*sin(th);
    delta_th = (Dright - Dleft)/wheel_base;

    x += delta_x;
    y += delta_y;
    th += delta_th;

ROS_INFO("Dx:%lf, dy:%lf, Dth:%lf",delta_x,delta_y,delta_th);
ROS_INFO("x:%lf, y:%lf, th:%lf",x,y,th);

lwheel_abs_ticks_prev = lwheel_abs_ticks_pres;
rwheel_abs_ticks_prev = rwheel_abs_ticks_pres;

    //since all odometry is 6DOF we'll need a quaternion created from yaw
    geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromRollPitchYaw(0,0,th);

    //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
    odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
    odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_footprint";

    odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
    odom_trans.transform.rotation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

    //send the transform
    odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

    //next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
    nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
    odom.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom.header.frame_id = "odom";

    //set the position
    odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
    odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
    odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

//Setting the diagonal element of covariance matrix
for(iIndex=0;iIndex <36;iIndex++)
{
    odom.pose.covariance[iIndex]=0.001;
}

    //set the velocity
    odom.child_frame_id = "base_footprint";
    odom.twist.twist.linear.x = vx;
    odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy; //vy;  //as it is differential drive
    odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth;

    //publish the message
    odom_pub->publish(odom);
```

}`void security_robot_yaw_publisher(ros::Publisher *yaw_pub)
{

```
tf::TransformBroadcaster yaw_broadcaster;
sensor_msgs::Imu yaw_sens;
//if(calibrated_yaw !=0)
{

    geometry_msgs::Quaternion yaw_quat_1 = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(calibrated_yaw);
    

    //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
        /*geometry_msgs::TransformStamped yaw_trans;
        yaw_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
        yaw_trans.header.frame_id = "yaw";
        yaw_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

    yaw_trans.transform.rotation = yaw_quad_1;
        
        //send the transform
        yaw_broadcaster.sendTransform(yaw_trans);*/

    //tf::Quaternion yaw_quad_2 = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(1,1,2);
    yaw_sens.header.stamp    = ros::Time::now();
    yaw_sens.header.frame_id = "yaw";

    yaw_sens.orientation = yaw_quat_1;

    for(iIndex=0;iIndex <9;iIndex++)
    {
        yaw_sens.orientation_covariance[iIndex]=0;
    }

    yaw_pub->publish(yaw_sens);
}
```

}

`

Thanks in Advance,
Nithin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194694/issue-with-robot_pose_ekf/) by [Nithin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20057/nithin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it's blowing up trying to invert a matrix. If I had to guess, your measurement covariances are wrong and are making the [innovation covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) singular (i.e., uninvertible). You have two main issues that I can see after a quick review:

```
//Setting the diagonal element of covariance matrix
for(iIndex=0;iIndex <36;iIndex++)
{
    odom.pose.covariance[iIndex]=0.001;
}
```

In this code block, you're not setting the diagonal indices. You're setting *all* the indices. The inverse of that matrix alone is singular. What you want is this:

```
//Setting the diagonal element of covariance matrix
for(iIndex=0;iIndex <36;iIndex+=7) // Note the index increment is now 7
{
    odom.pose.covariance[iIndex]=0.001;
}
```

Second, you've zeroed out the covariance matrix for your IMU measurement. No sensor can be completely without error, which is what a zero covariance implies.

```
for(iIndex=0;iIndex <9;iIndex++)
{
  yaw_sens.orientation_covariance[iIndex]=0;
}
```

Even though this might not cause the inversion issue you originally posted, you should change it to

```
for(iIndex=0;iIndex <9;iIndex+=4) // Note the index increment is now 4
{
  yaw_sens.orientation_covariance[iIndex]=0.1; // Or whatever you want. Just make it non-zero and positive.
}
```

I'm pretty sure the covariance arrays in messages default to all zeros anyway, so you shouldn't have to handle the off-diagonal elements.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nithin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20057/nithin/) on 2014-10-10**:
Thanks for the instructions. Will try this and update if this solves my issue

**Comment by [Nithin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20057/nithin/) on 2014-10-12**:
Thanks Moore. The issue got resolved after making changes as you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Nithin